# Not able to create a facebook Ad Account in java-ads-sdk

Tags: java, facebook, ads

I am not able to create an Ad account using java-ads-sdk from a business manager. Below is my code

```
Business business = new Business(707942606053966L, context);
        AdAccount adAccount = business.createAdAccount().setName("AD_ACCOUNT_1").setCurrency("INR").setTimezoneId(1L)
                .setEndAdvertiser("NONE").setInvoice(true).setIo(false).setPoNumber("1").execute();
```

I am getting the below exception

```
{"error":{"message":"(#270) Development access is not allowed to access business API post:Business\/adaccount.","type":"OAuthException","code":270,"fbtrace_id":"BYeRqnSnzQ7"}}
```

Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes. It requires a standard access which has to be requested from facebook. Thanks :)